# Is this logical deduction valid?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Is the following deduction valid?

Consider $$\lnot X \land ((Y \land \lnot Z) \lor (\lnot Y \land Z)).$$

Manipulating via distributive laws:

\begin{align*}
&=
[\lnot X \lor (Y \land \lnot Z)] \land [\lnot X \lor (\lnot Y \land Z)] \\ &= [(\lnot X \land Y) \lor (\lnot X \land \lnot Z)] \land [(\lnot X \land \lnot Y) \lor (\lnot X \lor Z)] \\ &= {[[{(\lnot X \land Y) \lor (\lnot X \land \lnot Z)] \lor (\lnot X \land \lnot Y)}] \land [{[(\lnot X \land Y) \lor (\lnot X \land \lnot Z)] \lor (\lnot X \lor Z)}]} \\ &= {[{[(\lnot X \land Y) \lor (\lnot X \land \lnot Y)] \lor (\lnot X \land \lnot Z)]} \land [{[(\lnot X \land Z) \lor (\lnot X \land \lnot Z)] \lor (\lnot X \land Y)}]} \\ &= [\lnot X \lor (\lnot X \land \lnot Z)] \land [\lnot X \lor (\lnot X \land Y)] \\ &= \lnot X \land \lnot X \\ &= \lnot X.
\end{align*}

Comment: No it's not right. You're supposed to be using distributive laws, but instead you're using de morgan's laws incorrectly.

Comment: So, is my very first step incorrect?

Comment: Yes, and most of your other steps because you do the same thing. E.g. the first step would be $=[\lnot X\land (Y\land \lnot Z)]\lor[\lnot X\land (\lnot Y\land Z)]$. Besides I don't think there is a way to meaningful reduce the expression since the right part is basically just $Y \:\text{XOR}\: Z$.

Comment: your very first step is incorrect. note that distributive law is as follows $A \vee (B \wedge C) \Leftrightarrow (A \vee B) \wedge (A \vee C)$

Comment: Terminological point.- If I say that A is equivalent to B , that is equivalent to C, etc. , I do not deduce, I make statements, I " judge". In order to make a deduction I have to use the word " therefore" , I have to infer something from something. What is true is that, as soon as I know that B is equivalent to A, I am allowed to deduce B from A ( and vice versa). But ordinarily, the deductibility relation ( i.e.  logical consequence relation)  is not symmétric ( whereas the equivalence relation has this symmetric property).

Answer (score 2):

You misused De Morgan's Laws. Using distributive laws, it will simply be just:

\begin{align*}
&=
\lnot X \land ((Y \land \lnot Z) \lor (\lnot Y \land Z))
\\ &= (\lnot X \land Y \land \lnot Z) \lor (\lnot X \land \lnot Y \land Z)
\end{align*}
That will be the most simple form of your problem, I believe.